# Coc nvim suggestion selection

Tags: vim, neovim

I have installed the plugin and also I can see the suggestions. But I am unable to select it I have tried enter, tab, space but still I can’t select it. I have to complete it myself and it is really hard.

Please help.

Comment: Use the plugin's various support channels.

Answer (score 9):

Just add these lines taken from [coc documentation](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) to your vimrc:

```
" Make <CR> to accept selected completion item or notify coc.nvim to format
" <C-g>u breaks current undo, please make your own choice.
inoremap <silent><expr> <CR> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm()
                              \: "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"
```

Comment: `or notify coc.nvim to format <C-g>u breaks current undo` - didn't get this